# Insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to make a POST-request and getting this error

{
"msg": "insert or update on table "client" violates foreign key constraint "FK_e61c5ecfaabf7e6d9285fbfb070""
}

My Client entity:

```
@Entity()
export default class Client extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  clientId: number;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: ClientStatus, default: ClientStatus.NOT_CLIENT })
  clientStatus: ClientStatus;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  countryOfResidence: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, length: 30 })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, length: 30 })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true, length: 30 })
  surName: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Passport)
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'passportId', name: 'passportId' })
  passportId: string;

  @OneToOne(() => AuthVerification)
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'mobilePhone', name: 'mobilePhone' })
  mobilePhone: string;

  @OneToOne(() => UserProfile, (userProfile) => userProfile.clientId)
  userProfile: UserProfile;
}
```

My AuthVerification entity:

```
@Entity()
class AuthVerification extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  @OneToOne(() => Client)
  mobilePhone: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false, length: 6 })
  verificationCode: string;
}
```

Line in migration where constraint key mentioned:

```
await queryRunner.query(
      `ALTER TABLE "client" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_e61c5ecfaabf7e6d9285fbfb070" FOREIGN KEY ("mobilePhone") REFERENCES "auth_verification"("mobilePhone") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`
    );
```

So, I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe you are inserting into client with a mobilePhone that doesn't exist in AuthVerification yet? The AuthVerification record must exist first before inserting a Client record.

Comment: @Mirodinho, so how i can record mobilePhone in AuthVerification first?